# fastboot flash %%i in (*.img) batch file

Tags: android, batch-file

im looking for the right way to flash multiple *.img files in the same folder without duplicating "fastboot flash xxxxx  xxxxx.img" command on all lines
I want the output to be like this

```
flash boot... OKAY
flash recovery... OKAY
flash fastboot... OKAY
flash fastboot... FAILED
```

I was using

```
for %%i in (*.img) do fastboot flash %%i %%i do @echo flash %%i ...OKAY
```

but the output is not what i want

```
Start Flashing ....
target reported max download size of 805306368 bytes
sending 'boot.img' (131072 KB)...
OKAY [  3.751s]
target reported max download size of 805306368 bytes
sending 'boot_b.img' (131072 KB)...
OKAY [  3.755s]
writing 'boot_b.img'...
FAILED (remote: (boot_b.img_a) No such partition) ::: fail because partition name contain file extension

target reported max download size of 805306368 bytes
sending 'frp.img' (512 KB)...
OKAY [  0.023s]
writing 'frp.img'...
FAILED (remote: (frp.img_a) No such partition)

target reported max download size of 805306368 bytes
sending 'modem.img' (262144 KB)...
OKAY [  7.520s]
writing 'modem.img'...
FAILED (remote: (modem.img_a) No such partition)
```

it shows FAILED No such partition in output
Because the partition name contain the file extension and It should be "fastboot flash filename filename.img"
for works correctly

```
for %%i in (*.img) do fastboot flash %%i %%i do @echo flash %%i ...ok
```

any help or suggestion to fix command ?

Comment: `for /?` - see the "modifiers" section. For example `%%~ni` is the name without extension.

Comment: Please don't include solutions in your question, post an answer instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution.

```
for %%i in (*.img) do fastboot flash %%~ni %%i  >nul 2>&1 && (
      echo - Writing %%~ni ... OKAY
     ) || (
     echo - Writing %%~ni ... FAILED
)
```

the output

```
- Writing boot_a ... OKAY
- Writing boot_b ... OKAY
- Writing dip ... OKAY
- Writing dsp_a ... OKAY
- Writing dtbo_a ... OKAY
- Writing dtbo_b ... OKAY
- Writing ffu ... OKAY
- Writing frp ... OKAY
- Writing fsc ... FAILED
- Writing fsg ... FAILED
- Writing imagefv_a ... OKAY
- Writing imagefv_b ... OKAY
- Writing mdtp_a ... OKAY
- Writing mdtp_b ... OKAY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%i in (*.img) do SET "writing="&for /f "tokens=1,2delims=' %%u in ('fastboot flash "%%~ni" "%%i"') do (
 IF DEFINED writing FOR /f %%y IN ("%%u") DO CALL ECHO %%writing%% %%%%y&SET "writing="
 IF "%%u"=="writing " SET "writing=%%~nv"
)
```

should do what I believe you want.

`%%i` gets the name of each file assigned to it in turn.

Having set `writing` to *nothing* (which makes `writing` undefined) the `fastboot` utility is then executed with the parameters `flash`, the name part of the filename and the full filename. `fastboot`'s output is then "tokenised" using `'` as a delimiter, so any line is split - any part before a `'` is assigned to `%%u` and the part before the next `'` is assigned to `%%v`.

`writing` starts undefined. If we find the word `writing`  (importantly including the space) in `%%u` then we set `writing` to the part between the first and second `'`s in `%%v`; treated as a filename (which it is) and removing the extension (`%%~nv`).

The next line processed will be the "FAILED/OKAY" report of which we want the first word, so we take `%%u` and use the default "token=1delims=, " to grab just that word to `%%y`; then use `call echo` to `echo` the required data in a subshell, which reparses `%%writing%% %%%%y` to `%writing% %%y`.

No guarantees since I have to simulate `fastboot`'s output for testing.

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation about tokenising - or choose from thousands of examples on SO